# What unofficial power supplies work for the Atari Jaguar?

Tags: atari-jaguar

I just recently bought an Atari Jaguar on ebay, but it was sold as is because there was no cords that came with it. I was planning on buying an official power supply, but I want to test it with one I already have. I just want to know if its safe to just test it with the power supply I have.

This is the specs for the adapter I have:

INPUT 120VAC 60Hz 21W
OUTPUT 9VDC 1200mA
and I think the polarity (+)---(@)--(-)

Comment: Your polarity diagram doesn't really show the polarity well.  I can't tell which is positive and which is negative.

Answer (score 4):

The official Atari Jaguar power supply outputs 9V at 1.2A, which means any power supply you use will need to output **exactly 9V** and **at least 1.2A**.  So your power supply will work assuming the connector fits and the polarity is correct.  The Jaguar uses a center negative power supply.

[image: Center Negative Symbol]

This is the symbol for center negative.  If your power supply has that, it will work.

Note the difference from a [center positive symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTFLy.png).

Answer (score 0):

I've used my power supply for guitar effect pedals, as they (usually) use a center negative power supply, are 9v output and are pretty cheap. I have a 1Spot daisy chained power supply - I'm thinking I could even power multiple system (Jaguar, Sega Genesis, etc...) using it - since it's made to daisy chain multiple 9v pedals from the same plug.

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=1spot